# Normalize measure to interval [0, 1] in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, measure, normalize

I have a dataset in 'Table1' as follows
[sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEF5W.jpg)
and calculate a measure of "Revenue per Customer" as follows

```
Revenue Per Customer = 

DIVIDE(SUM('Table1'[Revenue (GBP)]), SUM('Table1'[Number Of Customers]))
```

As a final step, I try to normalize the measure above into interval [0,1] so that 1 would be max value as follows

```
Normalized Revenue Per Customer = 

VAR Xi = 
DIVIDE(SUM('Table1'[Revenue (GBP)]), SUM('Table1'[Number Of Customers])) 
VAR MnX =     
MINX('Table1', 
DIVIDE(SUM('Table1'[Revenue (GBP)]), SUM('Table1'[Number Of Customers]))) 
VAR MxX =  
MAXX('Table1', DIVIDE(SUM('Table1'[Revenue (GBP)]), SUM('Table1'[Number Of Customers])))

RETURN DIVIDE(Xi-MnX , MxX - MnX)
```

but does not work. In the end, I need to add the normalized measure to a visual and select via filters the year, so the normalized measure should be automatically calculated per any year combination, i.e. 2019 or 2019 and 2020 etc.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: It's a good question, but it concerns statistics, not DAX. In DAX look at NORM.DIST() . Try it and if you will have problems with the result, please let me know. And, please, add you sample as a table to the question body, not a picture. Note, that if you want me to see you reply refere to me as @Mik.

Comment: @Mik thanks for your comment, but my question is about implementation in DAX so it concerns DAX. Also NORM.DIST() won't work for mapping any set of values to the [0,1] interval. The formula for doing so is mapped_value = (initial_value - MIN)/(MAX - MIN)

Comment: Hi, ok. I got the point. I'll try to help with the issue within 3-4 hours. It would be great If you can add a dummy table as link to excel file.

Comment: @Mik thanks for your reply. Please find in the answer below the dummy table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Normalized Revenue Per Customer = 

VAR Xi = [Revenue Per Customer]
VAR MnX = MINX(
    ALLSELECTED(Table1)
    , [Revenue Per Customer]
    )
VAR MxX = MAXX(
         ALLSELECTED(Table1)
    , [Revenue Per Customer]
    )

RETURN DIVIDE(Xi-MnX , MxX - MnX)
```

[image]

[image]

```
Normalized Revenue Per Customer = 

VAR Xi = [Revenue Per Customer]
VAR MnX = MINX(
    ALL(Table1[Store]) -- ALLSELECTED(Table1[Store]) if you plan to filter by store.
    ,[Revenue Per Customer]
    )
VAR MxX = MAXX(
    ALL(Table1[Store]) -- ALLSELECTED(Table1[Store]) if you plan to filter by store.
    ,[Revenue Per Customer]
    )

RETURN DIVIDE(Xi-MnX , MxX - MnX)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your [Normalized Revenue Per Customer] should be like this:

```
Normalized Revenue Per Customer = 
VAR Xi = 
DIVIDE(SUM(Table1[Revenue(GBP)]), SUM('Table1'[Number Of Customers]))
VAR MnX =     
MINX('Table1', 
DIVIDE([Revenue(GBP)], [Number Of Customers]))
VAR MxX =  
MAXX('Table1', DIVIDE([Revenue(GBP)],[Number Of Customers]))
RETURN DIVIDE(Xi-MnX , MxX - MnX)
```

If we test it with years comparison as slicer, It returns:

[image: Slicer_Action_01]

[image: Slicer_Action_02]

I hope This is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: ,, thanks for your reply, though I would like the result to end up with [Normalized Revenue per Customer] = 1 for the max value when plotting [Normalized Revenue per Customer] Vs. Store. So, in your example above for 2020 and 2021 London that has max value should end up with [Normalized Measure] = 1. Can you help me with that? Thanks..

Comment: Hi I added the solution and a screenshot to the bottom

Comment: @Mik thanks Mik, the 'Table' visual that you posted works Ok but the 'Line Chart' visual seems to still not work (see the images that I posted in my answer)

Comment: Ok, I'll check it today.